# AudioTrack couses stutters

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have an app streaming music to another phone via Bluetooth. The app decodes mp3 to pcm data and then sends it. The problem is the sound stutters sometimes, but plays ok other times. The play method looks like this:

```
public void Read()
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int _bufferSize;
        AudioTrack _output;

        _output = new AudioTrack(Android.Media.Stream.Music, 44100, ChannelOut.Stereo, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,
            10000, AudioTrackMode.Stream);
        _output.Play();

        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1000];
        //byte[] check = new byte[1];

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                    _output.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                    //mmOutStream.Write(check);
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
                }
            }
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

And after a while it stops and displays this:

```
02-03 19:08:58.019 W/AudioTrack( 3986): releaseBuffer() track 0xc5e2de00 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting
```

How would I fix this?

---

But then I just found out it plays OK when played from my Samsung A5 to better Samsung J7, but then it just stops, here is the log:

```
 02-04 15:44:12.816 W/AudioTrack( 2299): releaseBuffer() track 0xc6fa9380 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting
 Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7
 The thread 0x7 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 02-04 15:44:36.239 V/InputMethodManager( 2299): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@37c869a nm : com.companyname.sharethemusic ic=null
 02-04 15:44:36.239 D/InputMethodManager( 2299): startInputInner - Id : 0
 02-04 15:44:36.240 I/InputMethodManager( 2299): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
 02-04 15:44:36.248 D/InputTransport( 2299): Input channel constructed: fd=78
 02-04 15:44:36.248 D/InputTransport( 2299): Input channel destroyed: fd=72
 02-04 15:44:36.659 D/InputMethodManager( 2299): HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 2299
 02-04 15:44:36.712 D/BluetoothSocket( 2299): close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@6b2de90, channel: 7, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@c5befa8, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@a1a6ac1mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@c0c7266 impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@d0bf9a7 fd:java.io.FileDescriptor@2545e54, mSocketState: CONNECTED
 02-04 15:44:36.723 D/BluetoothAdapter( 2299): disable()
 02-04 15:44:38.062 D/BluetoothAdapter( 2299): onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
 02-04 15:44:38.062 D/BluetoothAdapter( 2299): Bluetooth is turned off, stop adv
 02-04 15:44:38.063 D/BluetoothAdapter( 2299): There are no active google scan apps, stop scan
 02-04 15:44:38.090 D/BluetoothAdapter( 2299): ondisableBLE
 02-04 15:44:38.090 D/BluetoothAdapter( 2299): There are no active google scan apps, stop scan
```

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your code like following .

```
int buffsize = AudioTrack.GetMinBufferSize(8000, ChannelOut.Mono, Encoding.Pcm16bit);
_output = new AudioTrack(Android.Media.Stream.Music, 8000, ChannelOut.Mono, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,
            buffsize*4, AudioTrackMode.Stream);
```

Comment: This code makes the player play at like 0,25x the normal speed

Comment: Try to set buffsize*4 as buffsize .